# how to establish a TCP connection using Java?

Tags: java, http, tcp, request

How can you establish a TCP connection by yourself, in other words, how is it possible to send a HTTP request and receive the HTTP reply from a server using java language? its relevant to say that this should be done without using an http library.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: To do this without HTTP Library it is possible but can get a hell of work if you will try to handle all topics like Transfer-Encoding, Keep-Alive, Chunking etc...
Why don't you want to use http library is this maybe an homework task from school?
Then the teacher will expect simple GET / HTTP1.0 as request and remove the part above the first empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple sample.

```
    try(final Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 80);
            final InputStream i = s.getInputStream();
            final OutputStream o  = s.getOutputStream()) {
    }
```

Comment: I can´t use any http libraries because this is a condition of the school project. thanks for all the replies. I'm beginning the study of networking and the essay is about devellop a webclient.  - you are supposed to establish the TCP connection by yourself, send the HTTP request and
receive the HTTP reply;
- the HTTP reply should then be presented to the user;
- prepare your client to proactively act to the different HTTP
replies. I'm a bit confused to do all this operations in java. thanks in advance for any help.